# Blow-up toric varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, toric-geometry

I have to take a talk of an hour and I have to talk about blow-up of toric varieties. Can you suggest me some interesting examples that I can present? How can I find a good reference for the theory needed? I'd like to do a talk rich of images and interesting examples. Thank you!

Comment: The best resource I know of about toric varieties is the (aptly named) book [Toric Varieties](https://books.google.it/books?id=AoSDAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cox+toric+varieties&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qs84Vf7bH4OzaYfigLAH&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=cox%20toric%20varieties&f=false) by Cox, Little, and Schenk. You will likely find something interesting in there.

Comment: Cox has also written a rather short and easy-read article (much shorter than the book). It can be found on his web page: http://www3.amherst.edu/~dacox/

Answer (score 8):

Off the top of my head, here is something you could try. (Everything you need should be in Fulton's book or Cox–Little–Schenck.)

1. Explain how blowing up a subvariety of a toric variety corresponds to subdivision of the fan. Illustrate with simple examples, like blowing up a point in $\mathbf P^2$ and a line in $\mathbf P^3$.
2. Now use this to explain how to resolve the birational map $\sigma: \mathbf P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^2$ defined by
   $$\sigma([x_0,x_1,x_2]) = [x_1x_2,x_0x_2,x_0x_1].$$
   (Punchline: you subdivide the standard fan in $\mathbf R^2$ in a certain way, then unsubdivide (?) in a different way to get a *different*, but isomorphic, fan.)
3. Next consider the analogous birational map $\Sigma: \mathbf P^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^3$ defined by
   $$\Sigma([x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]) = [x_1x_2x_3,x_0x_2x_3,x_0x_1x_3,x_0x_1x_2].$$
   Now there are lots of possibilities: you can blow up lines in different orders, and compare the result. Or you can blow up points to get a toric variety $X$, and study the birational map $\Sigma_X: X \dashrightarrow X$ induced by $\Sigma$. What properties does $\Sigma_X$ have? (Punchline: congratulations, you've invented flops!)

I'm deliberately being a bit sketchy here; I encourage you to work out the details of what I'm talking about. I hope that helps. Have fun!

Comment: I think your suggestions are great, but, at least for #1, it may be better to start with affine space rather than projective space, depending on the sophistication level of the audience.

Comment: Dear @MichaelJoyce, thanks for the correction. Yes, depending on the audience, one might have to adapt my suggestions. Fortunately, interesting things can happen even in the affine case, as you know: one gets a lot of mileage already by torically interpreting the fact that the square has two different diagonals!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thank you very much for the suggestions. Where can I find some material about points 1,2,3? What do you mean for resolve e birational map? Thank you.

Comment: Dear @user137921: as I mentioned, the books of Fulton and Cox-Little-Schenck contain all this material. "Resolve" means to blow up the domain of a birational map in a suitable way so that it extends to a regular map. The fact that birational maps can be resolved like this is the basic reason that we study blow-ups in the first place!